Error : X does not have valid feature names but SVC was fitted with feature names
print("predicted disease :",svc.predict(X_test.iloc[0].values.reshape(1,-1)))
print("Actual Disease :", y_test[0])
i am getting : UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but SVC was fitted with feature names   warnings.warn - How to fix this ? and also my flask app is keep on loading but not showing predicted disease
as it was suggested by other developer to convert df to array i have done that but it shows that X_test doesn't have iloc attribute error

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
